# Puppeteer is stuck on big xml url

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying open a big sitemap xml file with puppeteer and parse its content, but it seems to be waiting forever. Below is what I am doing:

```
    const response = await page.goto("xmlurl")
    await response.text()
```

The xml is 15 MBs with 20k entries in it. I just want to read its contents but I am guessing it is trying to parse it like an html file. Is there way to get only the raw text without all the parsing?

Comment: Use another http client lib like `axios, curl`...

Comment: Cannot use those, they are detected as bot. Only real browsers are not detected somehow. Even puppeteer without stealth plugin doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you can try `fetch` in `page.evaluate()` from the root of the site (to fit the CORS).